# Cannot access property passed via user provider

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a userContext like this :

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import * as userService from "./services/appService";


const UserContext = React.createContext();

export function useUserContext() {
  return useContext(UserContext);
}

export function UserProvider({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const { data } = await  userService.allDetails();
      setUser(data);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return <UserContext.Provider value={user}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>;
}
```

I'm wrapping routes with User Provider like this

```
<UserProvider>
 <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />\
 <Route path="/login" component={Login} />\
<ProtectedRoute path="/resetpassword" component={Reset} />
<ProtectedRoute path="/settings" component={Settings} />
<UserProvider>
```

I'm trying to access it inside a functional component like this:

```
function Settings(){
const user = useUserContext();
const id = user.id

useEffect(() => {
console.log(id)

 },[])

return (
.......
)

}
```

I'm getting user as undefined in Settings component.

Answer (score 1):

In the `UserProvider` component, you defined a state `user` with initial value of undefined, because you did not pass any value to `useState`. Even though you are making an API call to update the state of `user` state, but keep in mind that fetching is an asynchronous operation and may take time to finish, which is why when you try to access `user` context in `Settings` component, the value is still `undefined`. You could add an `if` statement check here to see if `user` context is truthy or not and use it if it's truthy only, which means that the fetch finished and `user` state has been updated

Comment: Note, even if it wasn't an asynchronous fetch, `user` would still initially be `undefined` because an effect is first run after the first render.

Comment: By conditionally rendering only when user is defined, the issue is components like Signup and Login doesn't render. what would be ideal approach in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Since the user is only loaded as an Effect after the first render of `UserProvider`, it is still undefined during the first render.

I suggest you suspend rendering the `UserProvider` and its contents until the fetch completed:

```js
export function UserProvider({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    userService.allDetails()
      .then(({ data }) => setUser(data));
  }, []);

  return !user ? null : (
    <UserContext.Provider value={user}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, you were right. 

Now the issue is Signup or Login where user is defined doesn't render with the conditional statement. Should I wrap just the protected routes with User Provider?

I have edited the routes in the question